# SKlearn classification models returning TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' when trying to fit

Tags: python, machine-learning, multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification

I am fairly new to building models; so please go easy :).  I am trying to build a multi-classification model using various model types (SGD, Decision Tree, etc), however, whenever I try to fit any of them, I am receive a TypeError:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

An example code I am using is as below:

```
sgd = SGDClassifier(loss='modified_huber', shuffle=True, random_state=101, average='micro')

sgd.fit(X_train,Y_train)
y_pred = sgd.predict(X_test)
```

I had previously ensured that the columns were of the same dtype:

```
for column in X_train.columns.tolist():
    X_train[column] = X_train[column].astype('float32')

Y_train = Y_train.astype('float32')
```

And I can verify that they are indeed float32 when using:

```
X_train.dtypes
Y_train.dtypes
```

So I am not sure why it is seeing any instances of a 'str'.  Could someone please advise? Thanks!

Comment: What line does the error appear in?

Comment: Error occurs in the sgd.fit(X_train, Y_train) line